# Apache rewrite rule for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I was trying to rewrite a url in apache but it is not working as i expected.  Here is how i defined in local environment

```
  Allow from all
  Satisfy Any
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteOptions Inherit
  RewriteRule ^(.*/)?email/?$ /api/v1/email [R=permanent,L]
```

I have defined this rewrite condition in mycompany.conf file which is located in the path

/etc/apache2/other

The url coming is "POST /items/50d42529dbc38e3d580002ff/email HTTP/1.1" 500 18750

I want to redirect /email to another path like /api/v1/email

I have defined a rails routes path for /items/50d42529dbc38e3d580002ff/email like this

match 'items/:id/email' => 'items#email', :as => :email_item, :via => :post

My question is based on rewrite rule it should go to api/v1/path and it shouldn't go to rails path that i defined in routes. It is not working like i thought.

I want to know whether my rewrite rule is correct or not and also i didn't define in .httaccess file. I included mycompany.conf file httpd.conf so i think it doesn't have a problem.

Please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry don't know much about rails, but using the debug log: RewriteLog "/myfolder/mylogfile.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 3  might give you some ideas, if not posting some of the results might help you get an answer quicker :)